# Why does << 32 not result in 0 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, unsigned, bit-shift, integer-overflow

This is false:

```
(0xffffffff << 31 << 1) === (0xffffffff << 32)
```

It seems like it should be true. Adding `>>> 0` anywhere does not change this.

Why is this and how can I correctly write code that handles `<< 32`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? And why? What value do you get for each operand?

Comment: [EcmaScript 5](http://i.imgur.com/0MWDiiS.png). Pay attention to step 7.

Comment: I encountered this in a node.js module for managing netmasks. It did a << (32 - mask) which failed for the 0.0.0.0/0 netmask. Since 32-0 == 32.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The shift operators always *effectively* has a right operand in the range 0-31.

From [the Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators):

> Shift operators convert their operands to 32-bit integers in big-endian order and return a result of the same type as the left operand. The right operand should be less than 32, but **if not only the low five bits will be used**.

Or from the [ECMAscript 5 standard](http://es5.github.io/#x11.7.1):

> The production ShiftExpression : ShiftExpression << AdditiveExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *ShiftExpression*.
> 2. Let *lval* be GetValue(*lref*).
> 3. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *AdditiveExpression*.
> 4. Let *rval* be GetValue(*rref*).
> 5. Let *lnum* be ToInt32(*lval*).
> 6. Let *rnum* be ToUint32(*rval*).
> 7. Let *shiftCount be the result of masking out all but the least significant 5 bits of > *rnum*, that is, compute *rnum* & 0x1F.
> 8. Return the result of left shifting *lnum* by *shiftCount* bits. The result is a signed 32-bit integer.

(And likewise for other shift operators.)

It's not entirely clear to me why this is the case, but Java and C# work the same way for their 32-bit integer types. (For 64-bit integer types, the operand is in the range 0-63.) See [JLS 15.19](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) for example.

My *guess* is that this is efficient on common processor platforms, but I don't have evidence of that...

Comment: It does seem weird. If it were a bit rotation then it'd make sense, but for bit shifting...?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I suspect it's for efficiency.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol most JS engines optimize SMIs extensively. V8 being a prime example.

Comment: Shouldn't it follow from this that `0xffffffff << 31 === 0xffffffff << 32` is `true`? It seems that the former has the value `-2147483648`, while the latter has the value `-1`.

Comment: @JLRishe `0xffffffff << 31 == 0x80000000`, whereas `0xffffffff << 32 == 0xffffffff` - these are clearly not equal ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yes, I surmised that much, but made a silly oversight. The low five bits of `32` is `0`, not `31`. :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Sometimes I type things before my brain has caught up :p I did mean 0x80000000.

Comment: but 0x80000000 << 1 == 0x00000000

Comment: That it is more logical for 0xffffffff << 32 to == 0x00000000 rather then 0xffffffff. I.e. that << 32 has the same effect as << 31 << 1. It means that a << 32 needs to be detected and handled as a special case to ensure a correct result.

Comment: @Killroy: Yes, that would be logical. But it's not the way that the language is defined, as my answer shows.