# Why bitwise shift acts differently when sequenced?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Why there are different results of bitwise left shift?

```
1 << 32;        # 1
1 << 31 << 1;   # 0
```

Comment: @Quentin because in general two shifts by 31 and 1 is the same as a single shift by 32. In a language that has longs that's what would happen http://ideone.com/BowETV

Comment: Another explanation on topic: [Why does << 32 not result in 0 in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288111/why-does-32-not-result-in-0-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of

> Let `shiftCount` be the result of masking out all but the least significant 5 bits of `rnum`, that is, compute `rnum & 0x1F`.

of how the `<<` operation is defined. See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-left-shift-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation

So according to it - `32 & 0x1F` equals 0

So `1 << 32` equals to `1 << 0` so is basically no op.

Whereas 2 consecutive shifts by 31 and 1 literally perform calculations

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript defines a left-shift by 32 to do nothing, presumably because it smacks up against the 32-bit boundary. You cannot actually shift anything more than 31 bits across.

Your approach of first shifting 31 bits, then a final bit, works around JavaScript thinking that shifting so much doesn't make sense. Indeed, it's pointless to execute those calculations when you could just write `= 0` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the shift count is considered modulo 32.

This itself happens because (my guess) this is how most common hardware for desktops/laptops works today (x86).

This itself happens because.... well, just because.

These shift limitations are indeed in some cases annoying... for example it would have been better in my opionion to have just one shift operator, working in both directions depending on the sign of the count (like `ASH` works for [Common Lisp](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_ash.htm)).